# jquery function not passing variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im not sure I am understanding passing variables correctly as this is not working for me and the result is "null"

```
/********************************
/ QUICK SEARCH FUNCTIONS
/*******************************/
$(function () {

    var id = null;
    var name = null;
    var label = null;

    function searchSelect() {
        $('.dropdown-menu > li > a').on("click", function() {
            $('.dropdown-toggle').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
            $('#input-tag').attr('placeholder', $(this).text());
            var id = $(this).data('name');
            var name = $(this).data('name');
            var label = $(this).data('label');
    });
    }searchSelect();

    $('#add-tag').on("click", function() {
        $('#tag-results').append('<input id="'+ id +'" type="hidden" name="' + name +'" value="test" />');
        $('#tag-results').append('<div class="tag">'+label+'<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button></div>');
    });

});
```

Comment: What did you expect it to do?

Comment: pass the variables from the dropdown click action to the add-tag click function

Comment: `id` in the handler you add in `searchSelect` is not the `id` you have defined in the outer function. You used `var` to create a *local variable*. But either way, `id` might still be `null` in your add-tag function because the user hasn't clicked the drop down yet.

Comment: why the down vote? i felt as someone learning this was a perfectly valid question/problem and i provided code and a clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside searchSelect, when you assign values to the vars id, name and label, using the prefix 'var' you're re-declaring those variables privately to the scope of the function.

Please remove the prefix 'var' when assigning values of the variables id, name and label, inside the searchSelect function and that should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to not declare new variables you need to remove the `var` declaration inside your `searchSelect()` or the variables outside of this function will not be overridden.

Like so:

```
$(function () {

    var id = null;
    var name = null;
    var label = null;

    function searchSelect() {
        $('.dropdown-menu > li > a').on("click", function() {
            $('.dropdown-toggle').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
            $('#input-tag').attr('placeholder', $(this).text());

            // These will now override the variables declared outside the function
            // If using the keyword 'var' in front of these you are instead
            // creating local variables that won't be accessible
            // from outside of the function scope
            id = $(this).data('name');
            name = $(this).data('name');
            label = $(this).data('label');
    });
    }searchSelect();

    $('#add-tag').on("click", function() {
        $('#tag-results').append('<input id="'+ id +'" type="hidden" name="' + name +'" value="test" />');
        $('#tag-results').append('<div class="tag">'+label+'<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button></div>');
    });

});
```